# Who will take the role of Friend functions in java as in C++?

Tags: java

Who will  take the role of Friend functions in java as in C++? How will it work in java ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest thing Java has to C++ friends is the default access modifier, also known as package-protected or package-private.  This allows access to members only from other classes within the same package.

This is also the best reason to place classes in the same package, rather than grouping into subpackages based on functionality.

Comment: "This is also the best reason to place classes in the same package" - do you mean *all* classes?

Comment: No, of course not.  I mean classes that would have otherwise been grouped into subpackages based on functionality.  That wasn't clear?

Comment: If it helps - I am not arguing against namespacing in any way.  I am talking about after the namespacing has been worked out.

Answer (score 7):

There's no concept of a friend function in Java.  Your best bet is to learn about how Java does visibility - package-private (the default) in particular may be interesting to you --
[here's a quick tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your design is a little off. There really shouldn't be a need to have a friend function and that's why Java didn't include it in its language. Functions should be next to where the data it uses is located and if not then that data should be passed into the function as a parameter. In my opinion, Friend Functions go against the major ideas of OO programming. C++ tends to like to allow you to create non-OO programs even though the language fully supports the concepts that OO programming believes in.

I would consider modifying your design to put the functionality closer to where the data lives, then you really won't have this problem. However, this is not always possible especially if you are working with a legacy system. In that case, you should consider adapter classes, getters and setters, or parameters. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

The friend function is demerit of OOPs concept because it is used to access a class member function from the outside. That's why it has been removed from Java.